# How to install joy package on jade?

Tags: ros, joy-node, joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to use the joy package for an existing project which is using ros jade. (Ubuntu)

I'm following [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/joy/Tutorials/ConfiguringALinuxJoystick).
When I try to do `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-joy` I get an error that ros-indigo-joy could not be found. Is this the wrong version, or am I doing something else wrong?

I basically don't know anything about ros, but I now have to work on this existing project, to add a new functionality. For the node that I wrote, I can compile it using `cmake .` and  `rosmake` and it works fine with the rest of the project. So at first I tried to just copy the code from joy, and compile it in the same way. This compiles seemingly fine, but my node doesn't find the joy one and therefore can't receive any messages.
I assume that this is not the right way to integrate something like joy into an already existing project, right? What would be the correct way to do it - could it even work if I just apt-get installed it?

I'd really appreciate any help!

**Edit:** I did get it to work eventually. It wans't possible to install it via apt get. Unfortunately, the rest of this project was also not made using catkin but rosmake (and even though we are on jade - don't ask me why...), so I was hesistant to change anything about that, for fear of breaking it. So if anyone is looking for an answer to this question, below is a good explanation on how you should actually do it.

What ended up working for me was to clone the package code into my directory, and run `cmake .`, `make`, `rosmake`(didn't work without make in there).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243758/how-to-install-joy-package-on-jade?/) by [Zaunkönig](https://answers.ros.org/users/27980/zaunk%C3%B6nig/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have followed the [Guide: Ubuntu install of ROS Jade](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Ubuntu) and configured your Ubuntu repositories. Then you can run `sudo apt-get install ros-jade-joy`.

It is also OK to install a ROS node from source, but I can't address the reason why your joy doesn't function well from the info you gave.

It is strong recommended to go through all the [ROS beginner tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials).

---

If there is no `ros-jade-joy` in the apt repositories, you have to install from source. So go to your catkin workspace and clone that source code, and make the code. Then check if joy has been installed.

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/src
git clone https://github.com/ros-drivers/joystick_drivers.git

cd ~/catkin_ws
catkin_make

rospack find joy
```

---

Originally posted by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) with karma: 763 on 2016-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zaunkönig](https://answers.ros.org/users/27980/zaunk%C3%B6nig/) on 2016-09-14**:
Thanks for your input! I've tried that, but I get the same error (package ros-jade-joy could not be found).
Unfortunately, I don't know anything about the ros installation on that computer, since I didn't set it up. (I'm definitely way out of my depth here - I don't usually work with ros.)

**Comment by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) on 2016-09-14**:
So, just follow the install guide of ROS Jade and ROS beginner tutorials.

**Comment by [Zaunkönig](https://answers.ros.org/users/27980/zaunk%C3%B6nig/) on 2016-09-14**:
I'm not sure what you mean - do you think it's a problem with the local ros installation? Because I don't think I can change that. After looking through the installation tutorial, I tried `apt-cache search ros-jade` - ros-jade-joy is not among the packages it lists.